How do I use an existing secondary range or subnetwork for the control plane's network?
I'm creating a private cluster so I need to specific a range for the back plane.
I'm using terraform, this field is for this configuration option: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster#master_ipv4_cidr_block
I cannot find any docs that explain whether or not I can pre create the subnetwork.
I don't want to let GKE create the network, I want to pre-create and manage it as I do for the pod and service ranges, but when I use the range of an existing sub-network (or secondary range of a subnetwork) I get an error: Error waiting for creating GKE cluster: Google Compute Engine: An IP range in the peer network (10.8.8.0/28) overlaps with an IP range in the local network...
Is this just not possible? Its annoying because I want to pre-create the entire networking setup first and then create clusters.
It would be a hassle to have to create the cluster first, then modify the this network after GKE creates it- if I need to do any firewalling, logging config, etc.
